# local PDF file scraping in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

I have uploaded a pdf via a MEAN stack web application using fs.  I want to extract certain fields from the pdf and display them on the web app.  I have looked at a couple npm packages like pdf.js, pdf2json.  I can't figure out the documentation and javascript callbacks used in the examples available.  Please help!

Answer (score 2):

I hope I can help answer your question. Using pdf2json can be used to parse a pdf and extract the text. There are a couple of steps that need to be taken to get it working. I have adapted the example from https://github.com/modesty/pdf2json.

The setup is to install pdf2json in the node app, and also underscore. The example page didn't explain the need to define your own callback functions. It also used `self` instead of `this` to register them. So, with the appropriate changes the code to extract all the text from the pdf will be something like this:

```
// Get the dependencies that have already been installed
// to ./node_modules with `npm install <dep>`in the root director
// of your app 

var _ = require('underscore'),
    PDFParser = require('pdf2json');

var pdfParser = new PDFParser();

// Create a function to handle the pdf once it has been parsed.
// In this case we cycle through all the pages and extraxt
// All the text blocks and print them to console.
// If you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(pdf))` you will 
// see how the parsed pdf is composed. Drill down into it
// to find the data you are looking for.
var _onPDFBinDataReady = function (pdf) {
  console.log('Loaded pdf:\n');
  for (var i in pdf.data.Pages) {
    var page = pdf.data.Pages[i];
    for (var j in page.Texts) { 
      var text = page.Texts[j];
      console.log(text.R[0].T);
    }
  }
};

// Create an error handling function
var _onPDFBinDataError = function (error) {
  console.log(error);
};

// Use underscore to bind the data ready function to the pdfParser
// so that when the data ready event is emitted your function will
// be called. As opposed to the example, I have used `this` instead
// of `self` since self had no meaning in this context
pdfParser.on('pdfParser_dataReady', _.bind(_onPDFBinDataReady, this));

// Register error handling function
pdfParser.on('pdfParser_dataError', _.bind(_onPDFBinDataError, this));

// Construct the file path of the pdf
var pdfFilePath = 'test3.pdf';

// Load the pdf. When it is loaded your data ready function will be called.
pdfParser.loadPDF(pdfFilePath);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.  I have been trying to dig into the data but it looks like whenever i console.log(JSON.stringify(pdf)) right after the dataready function loads.  It will not display any data besides %n.  it doesn't seem to be picking up the data from the pdf.  console.log(text.R[0].T) seems to be logging the pdf but prints out very scattered pieces of the PDF text.

Comment: Please post the function that you are registering for onDataReady. I tried this with some basic PDFs but I don't onow how it goes with complex PDFs. If you can provide an example of the same format  PDF you are parsing I can try with that.

Comment: I am using the same exact function listed above in one of my server side controllers.

Comment: For the pdf I am using a invoice template / pdf.  It should be a normal pdf I also tried ones with just text.  Will post answer with my code.

Comment: Try doing JSON.stringify(page) in the for loop after the page has been assigned. You might need to explore using different keys, as there can be a lot of data in PDFs. I also tried JSON.stringify(pdf) and it didn't work here either, perhaps the object is too large, however it worked with the individual page.

Answer (score 0):

I am running the code out of my server side controller.

```
module.exports = (function() {
return {
    add: function(req, res) {
        var tmp_path = req.files.pdf.path;
        var target_path = './uploads/' + req.files.pdf.name;
        fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            // delete the temporary file, so that the explicitly set temporary upload dir does not get filled with unwanted files
            fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
                if (err) throw err;
            //edit here pdf parser

            res.redirect('#/');

            });
        })
    },
    show: function(req, res) {

    var pdfParser = new PDFParser();

    var _onPDFBinDataReady = function (pdf) {
      console.log('Loaded pdf:\n');

      for (var i in pdf.data.Pages) {

        var page = pdf.data.Pages[i];
        // console.log(page.Texts);
        for (var j in page.Texts) { 
          var text = page.Texts[j];
          // console.log(text.R[0].T);

        }
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(pdf));
    };
    // Create an error handling function
    var _onPDFBinDataError = function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    };
    pdfParser.on('pdfParser_dataReady', _.bind(_onPDFBinDataReady, this));
    // Register error handling function
    pdfParser.on('pdfParser_dataError', _.bind(_onPDFBinDataError, this));
    // Construct the file path of the pdf
    var pdfFilePath = './uploads/Invoice_template.pdf';
    // Load the pdf. When it is loaded your data ready function will be called.
    pdfParser.loadPDF(pdfFilePath);

},

//end controller
```

}

Comment: My client side controller automatically runs the show function.  The uploaded pdf is in my uploads folder which the parse function is pointed at.  "Invoice_Template.pdf".  The idea for this application is to scrape data from a list of pdf's in the uploads folder and be able to list them in the web application.